# Checking an image file size in bytes

Tags: c#

The image size is about 2.5MB

This code gives me the right size:

```
var fileLength = new FileInfo(path).Length;
```

This code gives me about 600KB

```
Image image= Image.FromFile(path);
byte[] imageByte = imageToByteArray(image);
long legnth= imageByte.Length;

public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

What am i missing?

The problem is that i recive the image in byte[] so..

Comment: what does the `imageToByteArray` do?

Comment: I believe problem is in your `igameToByteArray` implementation

Comment: File usually contains image in compressed format (let it be RLE or JPEG), while Image in memory is uncompressed bitmap (array of pixels in short).

Comment: yes, you guys are right, the format was swrong, thx

Comment: there you have it you force the format of the target image to be `png` which is probably different from the format the image was originally saved with

Comment: Why would you ever load a file from disk, parse it as some form of bitmap picture, then save it again, probably using a different algorithm than when it was first created, into memory, and then check how much memory that saving required?

Answer (score 5):

```
var fileLength = new FileInfo(path).Length;
```

*is similar to this:*

```
byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"yourimage.ext");
int size = buffer.Length;
```

`System.Drawing.Image` object holds raw uncompressed bitmap. When you call `imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` the bitmap gets compressed with different image/compression algorithm or a same algorithm but different options and that's why you have difference in image size.

Answer (score 1):

This code working fine ..

```
//your filePath  ex: /document/mypersonal/ram.png
var fileLength = new FileInfo (FilePath).Length;
public static string GetFileSize(fileLength)
{
    string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
    int order = 0;
    while (fileLength >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length) {
        order++;
        fileLength = fileLength/1024;
    }
    string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", fileLength, sizes[order]);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `Length` of your byte array is correct, the problem is, as @Kuba Wyrostek mentioned, is that you are most probably changing the format of the file from a loosely uncompressed bitmap to a PNG and *then* checking the size, which will return a different value.

The most trustworthy value you can depend on will be

```
var fileLength = new FileInfo(path).Length;
```